# Which is a better way - create fragment via Java code or XML

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was wondering, which is a better/ recommended way to create `Fragment`? Creation via Java code or creation via XML?

### Creation via Java code

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start" />
```

---

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    this.homeMenuFragment = HomeMenuFragment.newInstance();
    t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, homeMenuFragment);
    t.commit();
} else {
    this.homeMenuFragment = (HomeMenuFragment)(this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame));
}
```

### Creation via XML code

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
    android:name="org.yccheok.xxx.HomeMenuFragment"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start" />
```

---

```
this.homeMenuFragment = (HomeMenuFragment)(this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame));
```

For me, since both achieves the same outcome, it seems that creation via XML code is better. Is there any case, where we should prefer creation via Java code?

Comment: This is a really good question, and I'm excited to see if there is a difference, but I suspect with the title as-is it looks opinion-based. Can you make the title less subjective?

Comment: I usually use the code creating and I recommend it to you. It will give you more control with replacing and transactions. In this case you have no parameter newInstance method, so it will work the same, but what if you will need to pass parameter to new fragment? I think it will be problematic to pass parameter to xml. In code creating you just add parameter to newInstance method and its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments that are defined statically in an XML layout cannot be detached/removed. That's the main difference. If you don't ever need to do that, then feel free to declare it in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Your post make me think...
Well, one obvious thing about creating fragments via XML layout is that the fragment is static, hence not able to change by Java code. Perhaps it is fine by you. So let's move on from that.

The benefits of using the Java code:

- The ability to pass data via `newInstance()`. It could have been `HomeMenuFragment.newInstance(param1, param2, ...)`, for example.
- With `FragmentTransaction`, you can add to Backstack.